# Automatic clientside Backup of (Hosted Exchange / Outlook) mails

Tags: email, backup, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

Does anyone recommend or know a good solution to backup my hosted exchange hosted mails? Client-side I am using Outlook 2010 and the mails are 'only' stored in .ost / offline cache files & I could go ahead and attach a .pst file which I manually copy my mails to, but I'd rather have an automatic solution that does that reliably without me accidentally forgetting mails etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use Outlook's [AutoArchive feature](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/autoarchive-settings-explained-HA010362337.aspx)?

Comment: Don't know if I could because I don't even have that option under File > Options > Advanced, see: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6915/Outlook2010.PNG

Comment: Looks like this feature is disabled by your system administrator. Can you check this?

Comment: Well this is my system (not in an AD or anything... I am a local Admin and all that). I assume that it has something to do with my account being an Exchange one & not a e.g. pop3/imap one.

Comment: You have Exchange Online Archive option enabled then. In this case Outlook AutoArchive option is disabled.